Имя "listOfUsers" не существует в текущем контексте. Что делать?
        public UserPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AppContext db = new AppContext();
            List<User> users = db.Users.ToList();
            listOfUsers.ItemsSource = users;

        }

Хочу реализовать вывод всех пользователей в окно программы, но выдает ошибку "Имя "listOfUsers" не существует в текущем контексте.".
Ни чего не пробовал, так как не понимаю, что тут не так.

Очевидно, что компонента с именем listOfUsers в данном классе нету. И замечу, что в WPF так не принято действовать, научитесь работать с привязками. У вас должно быть DataContext = this; далее свойство public ... Items { get; set;} и в XAML простая привязка: <ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}">.

Начните с того, с чего вы взяли что там оно должно быть? Откуда-то эта убеждённость есть? Откуда? Покажите. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Смотрите, listOfUsers не существует в текущем контексте, потому что у Вас нет на странице DataGrid элемента, например, с названием listOfUsers. Вам необходимо добавить в разметку этот элемент. Кроме того, советую посмотреть на метаните тему по созданию wpf приложений. Там вы найдете всю нужную вам информацию
